# Overlay when burger button is clicked on and disabling it through same button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem on how to make an overlay working as I want. The problem is that when I click on the burger button, the overlay covers the bootstrap navbar and even the sliding menu. What I want is that the overlay only affects the HTML body, not including the navbar and the sidebar. Moreover, I want to disable the overlay through the same button but I dont know how to manage that too. Any help. Code is below.

```js
function on() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}

//mobile menu slide from the left
$('[data-toggle="slide-collapse"]').on('click', function() {
    $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
    $navMenuCont.animate({'width':'toggle'}, 350);
});
```

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle" data-toggle="slide-collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" onclick="on()" onclick="off()">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#myPage">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#band">BAND</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tour">TOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#myPage">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#band">BAND</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tour">TOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MORE
          <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Media</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
    
<div id="overlay"></div>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for your navbars.

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element
>   in the following scenarios:
>
> 1. Element with a position value "absolute" or "relative" and
>      z-index value other than "auto".

You need to add:

```
navbar {
  z-index: 5;
}

#myNavbar {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}
```

This will allow them to stack relative to the body and the overlay and whatever else you have. You might also move the overlay above them in the DOM, just so I guess semantically (?) it would be stacked before your navbars. But that's probably not required.

Comment: dgig, when I applied what you proposed above, the navbars where being shown overlapping on each other.

Comment: dgig, actually you were right, I played a bot around with the stacking, and it worked a charm. thanks man